# CAPACITOR_ANDROID_STUDIO_PATH environment variable in Ionic 5

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework, ionic5, angular12

Tried to add `CAPACITOR_ANDROID_STUDIO_PATH` environment variable as.

```
import { CapacitorConfig } from '@capacitor/cli';

const config: CapacitorConfig = {
  appId: 'com.barqrscanner.app',
  appName: 'barqrscannerapp',
  webDir: 'www',
  bundledWebRuntime: false
};

export interface PluginsConfig {
  [CAPACITOR_ANDROID_STUDIO_PATH: string]: | {
        [CAPACITOR_ANDROID_STUDIO_PATH: string]: 'D:\\android-studio-canary\\bin\\studio64.exe';
      }
    | undefined;
}

export default config;
```

If I try to add it in the.

```
const config: CapacitorConfig = {
  appId: 'com.barqrscanner.app',
  appName: 'barqrscannerapp',
  webDir: 'www',
  bundledWebRuntime: false,
  CAPACITOR_ANDROID_STUDIO_PATH: 'D:\\android-studio-canary\\bin\\studio64.exe'
};
```

will give error as this.
[image]

`ionic build` works but when I run `npx cap open android` both of them `CapacitorConfig` and `PluginsConfig` doesn't work
it shows this problem.

```
    PS D:\Projects\BarQrScannerApp> npx cap open android
[error] Unable to launch Android Studio. Is it installed?
        Attempted to open Android Studio at:
        You can configure this with the CAPACITOR_ANDROID_STUDIO_PATH environment variable.
```

I referenced it from here.
https://capacitorjs.com/docs/config

**Update 1:**
In `capacitor.config.json` I've used as.

```
{
  "appId": "com.enappd.capBarcodeScanner",
  "appName": "ionic-capacitor-barcode-scanner",
  "bundledWebRuntime": false,
  "npmClient": "npm",
  "webDir": "www",
  "windowsAndroidStudioPath": "D:\\android-studio-canary\\bin\\studio64.exe",
  "cordova": {
    "preferences": {
      "ScrollEnabled": "false",
      "android-minSdkVersion": "19",
      "BackupWebStorage": "none",
      "SplashMaintainAspectRatio": "true",
      "FadeSplashScreenDuration": "300",
      "SplashShowOnlyFirstTime": "false",
      "SplashScreen": "screen",
      "SplashScreenDelay": "3000"
    }
  }
}
```

For Angular 10 now for Angular 12 is using as `.ts` extension for `capacitor.config.ts` now how do I implement something like this `"windowsAndroidStudioPath": "D:\\android-studio-canary\\bin\\studio64.exe"`.

Answer (score 9):

On Ubuntu 16.04 export this variable in .bashrc file

```
echo export CAPACITOR_ANDROID_STUDIO_PATH="custom-path/android-studio/bin/studio.sh" >> ~/.bashrc
source ~/.bashrc
```

Or just run before `ionic cap open android`

```
export CAPACITOR_ANDROID_STUDIO_PATH="custom-path/android-studio/bin/studio.sh"
ionic cap open android
```

Comment: OP is using "windowsAndroidStudioPath" in their question as the old configuration. Your solution is for Ubuntu so unfortunately it is not helpful.

Comment: @nCr78 Other individuals can still benefit from this response.

Comment: To get your android path run - whereis studio.sh

Comment: You'll need to run `source ~/.bashrc` or `source ~/.zshrc` (if you're runing zsh) after the first command, or restart you terminal in order for it to work.

Answer (score 0):

Environment variables are configured in your **operating system** not in your App.

> CAPACITOR_ANDROID_STUDIO_PATH: The path to Android Studio executable
> on your system.
> https://capacitorjs.com/docs/config#environment-variables

if you like to know how to set environment variables in *Windows* you can refer to:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/26223/environment-variable.html

if you like to know how to set environment variables in *Linux Ubuntu* you can refer to:

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EnvironmentVariables

Comment: `{
 "appId": "io.ionic.starter.Udemy.Course",
 "appName": "ionic-angular-course",
 "bundledWebRuntime": false,
 "npmClient": "npm",
 "webDir": "www",
 "windowsAndroidStudioPath": "D:\\android-studio-canary\\bin\\studio64.exe",
 "plugins": {
  "SplashScreen": {
   "launchShowDuration": 0
  }
 },
 "cordova": {},
 "server": {
  "cleartext": true,
  "url": "http://192.168.1.10:8101"
 }
}` I've used as like this before it works now how do I use it in this angular 12

Comment: This part is on angular 10 which I have shown.