# Configure CAPACITOR_ANDROID_STUDIO_PATH environment variable on windows machine using WSL Ubuntu

Tags: android-studio, ubuntu, ionic-framework, environment-variables, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I have a ionic angular application.
When I run 'ionic capacitor build android' from WSL

I get the following errors:

```
[INFO] Ready for use in your Native IDE!

       To continue, build your project using Android Studio!

> capacitor open android
[capacitor] [error] Unable to launch Android Studio. Is it installed?
[capacitor]         Attempted to open Android Studio at: /usr/local/android-studio/bin/studio.sh
[capacitor]         You can configure this with the CAPACITOR_ANDROID_STUDIO_PATH environment variable.
```

I have android studio installed and additionally have set the system env variable for CAPACITOR_ANDROID_STUDIO_PATH with the path to its windows location.

I have also tried the suggested fixes on here [CAPACITOR_ANDROID_STUDIO_PATH environment variable in Ionic 5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68058470/capacitor-android-studio-path-environment-variable-in-ionic-5)
which also doesn't work

Wondering if anyone can help

Thanks

Comment: So if the person who gave a -1 please explain that would be great. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Had the exact same error. My Android Studio is at a different location as I use the snap.

So first figure out where studio is:

```
which android-studio
```

And then add the variable to your .bashrc (or e.g. .zshrc):

```
echo export CAPACITOR_ANDROID_STUDIO_PATH="/snap/bin/android-studio" >> ~/.bashrc
```

Restart your terminal and it should work.

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I did:

Step 1: Identity the location of your studio.sh

There could be a lot of location where it's location. For me, I installed Android Studio from Ubuntu Software where the installed location is in

`/snap/android-studio/current/android-studio/bin/studio.sh`

Step 2: Add to Environment variable

`vim ~/.bashrc`

Then append this line with your location of studio.sh like this:

`export CAPACITOR_ANDROID_STUDIO_PATH="/snap/android-studio/current/android-studio/bin/studio.sh"`

Step 3: Restart terminal or type in `$ source ~/.bashrc`

I hope this helps.